# How should I effectively display my manual?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I'm developing an Android Application and I need to add a manual, but I am bad at designing, how should I effectively display my manual? Can you provide a sample image to give me a better understanding, thanks in advance!

Some parts of the manual that I made:

```html
<center><b>Appendix A<br>
Brief Instruction Manual</b>
</center>
<ol type="I">
  <li>Creating a Quiz with All Three Question Formats Present</li>
  <br>
  <ol>
    <li>
      Click the <i>Plus/Positive symbol</i> at the upper right corner of the Home screen. The user will be redirected to the <i>Create Quiz</i> module.
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      Supply the necessary quiz <i>title</i>.
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      Supply the necessary quiz <i>duration</i>.
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      Supply the necessary quiz <i>description</i>.
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      Press the <i>SUBMIT</i> button to conclude the process. This submits all the information for recording and it will redirect the user to the <i>Home</i> module.
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      Locate and click the quiz title of the newly created quiz. It will redirect the user to the <i>Create Questionnaire</i> module.
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      Once inside the <i>Create Questionnaire</i> module, click the spinner to select a particular quiz format and then press the <i>ADD SECTION</i> button. The chosen format will appear at the space below the <i>ADD SECTION</i> button.
      <br>
      <br>Repeat the step until all three quiz formats have been selected.
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      Click the <i>Identification</i> section to commence creating identification questions. The user will be redirected to the <i>Identification Question/s</i> module.
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      Once inside the <i>Identification Question/s</i> module, click the <i>ADD QUESTION</i> button at the lower right corner of the screen. Clicking the <i>ADD QUESTION</i> button will redirect the user to the <i>Create Identification Question</i> module.
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      Supply the necessary identification question statement.
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      Supply the correct answer to the question statement.
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      Click the <i>DONE</i> button to conclude the process. Clicking the <i>Done</i> button will redirect the user back to the <i>Identification Question/s</i> module allowing him to create additional identification questions, update an existing identification
      question statement/s, or delete a particular question statement.
      <ol type="a">
        <br>
        <li>
          Creating additional identification question. The user needs to repeat the routine starting from Step no. 9.
        </li>
        <br>
        <li>
          Updating an existing question.
          <ol type="i">
            <br><li>
              Click the question statement of the particular question that needs to be updated. It will redirect the user back to the <i>Create Identification Question</i> module where he can update the contents.
            </li><br>
            <li>
              Click the UPDATE button to conclude the process. The user will be redirected back to the Identification Question/s module.
            </li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      Once done creating identification questions, click the <i>Back</i> button<i>/arrow pointing to the left</i> at the upper-leftmost corner of the <i>Identification Question/s</i> module. It will redirect the user back to the <i>Create Questionnaire</i> module.
    </li><br>
    <li>
    Click the <i>True or False</i> section to commence creating true or false questions. It will redirect the user to the <i>True or False Question/s</i> module.
    </li><br>
    <li>
    Once inside the <i>True or False Question/s</i> module, click the <i>ADD QUESTION</i> button at the lower right corner of the screen. It will redirect the user to the <i>Create True or False Question</i> module.
    </li><br>
    
  </ol>

  <li>Taking A Particular Quiz with All Three Question Formats Present</li>
  <li>Viewing Scores
    <ol>
      <li>
        Locate and click the particular quiz at the Home module. It will redirect the user to the <i>Quiz</i> module.
      </li>
      <li>
        Once inside, click the <i>SCORES</i> button. It will redirect the user to the <i>Score</i> module where all the scores of that particular quiz are listed.
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
    
  <li>Deleting a Quiz</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

In such cases using WebView, but if you dont have this then using this

```
<string name="about_text">
  <![CDATA[ 
    Author: Name<br/><br/>Description text, changelog, licences etc... ]]>
</string>
```

Comment: Web view? Can you elaborate more, I'm new with Android, what does that CDATA do?

Comment: If you have manual in Web Page only then you need use WebView.

Comment: Oh, my manual is text only, I put it in html just to show you how it looks in my word office. I was wondering if you could show me a paint sample to better show my manual. I have little creativity in me.